# Service makes the UI freeze

Tags: android

My application has a database where queued items will be stored if it doesn't notice any connectivity to Wifi or mobile network, like 3G og 4G. My problem is:

I have a `BroadcastReciever` which is registrered this way:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if(networkMonitor == null)
     networkMonitor = new CaseQueueReceiver();      
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
  registerReceiver(networkMonitor, filter);
}
```

My `BroadcastReciever` is starting a `Service` to pick out items from this database and send them over either a webservice or mail. My BrodcastReciever is like this:

```
public class CaseQueueReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    boolean available;
    QueueDB queueDB;
    int count;


    public CaseQueueReceiver() {
        queueDB = new QueueDB(ContextHelper.context());
        count = queueDB.countUnsentCases();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            String typeName = info.getTypeName();
            String subtypeName = info.getSubtypeName();
            available = info.isAvailable();

            Log.i("Network Monitor", "Network Type: " + typeName + ", subtype: " + subtypeName + ", available: " + available);

            if (available && count > 0) {
                Intent service = new Intent(context, SendQueuedCasesService.class); 
                context.startService(service);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if the internet connection is available and the database contains something, I will start a service to send these items in the database.

My Service looks like this:

```
public class SendQueuedCasesService extends Service {


    boolean available;
    DatabaseHandler db;
    QueueDB queueDB;
    HashMap<String, String> queueHashMap;
    CreateTransaction transaction;
    String pcn, file;
    int sent;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();   

        db = new DatabaseHandler(ContextHelper.context());
        queueDB = new QueueDB(ContextHelper.context());
        queueHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        transaction = new CreateTransaction(ContextHelper.context());

        queueDB = new QueueDB(this);
        int count = queueDB.countUnsentCases();
        Log.w("Unsent cases count: ", Integer.toString(count)); 

        if (count > 0) {

            queueHashMap = queueDB.getUnsetCases(); 
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = queueHashMap.entrySet().iterator(); 

            while(it.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry pairs = it.next(); 
                pcn = pairs.getKey().toString();
                Log.w("PCN in Queued Cases: ", pcn); 

                file = pairs.getKey().toString();
                Log.w("Nist File Path: ", file); 

                try 
                {
                    sent = transaction.createTransaction(pcn, file);

                    if(sent == -2) 
                    {
                        queueDB.deleteUnSentCase(pcn);
                        db.updateDB(pcn, ""); 
                    }
                    else 
                        break; 

                } catch(MailException e) {
                    Log.e("MailException: ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkflowChooser.getCurrentWorkflow());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I start the application this will block the UI for a while and then show the UI. A other problems is that this service isn't triggered if I turn off and the on the WiFi again. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that when I start the application this will block the UI for a while and then show the UI.

Service runs in UI thread. That's the problem.

Comment: I thought that the service didn't runned on the UI thread. Should I fire off a AsyncTask from the service then? So: `BroadCastReciever->Service->AsyncTask` ?

Comment: If you want to do long running operation Service, you have two options: spawn new thread(AsyncTask could do the job), or use IntentService(which already runs in separate thread).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `IntentService`. It will handle all the threading for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a new thread which handles the Service.